# Expect-regex positive lookbehind

Tags: expect

So I'm trying to use expect to automate logging into a switch and grabbing the interface associated with a mac address, but whenever I try to use a positive lookbehind regex it errors out. 
Here is what the input looks like:

```
VLAN ID  MAC Address         Interface  IfIndex  Status
-------  ------------------  ---------  -------  ------------
100      13:3N:K2:98:33:09   0/2        2        Static
100      52:0L:H9:74:6B:GG   0/8        8        Static
100      85:2F:E7:02:25:74   0/10       10       Static
```

And here is the code:

```
expect -c "
...
send \"show mac-addr-table\r\";
expect -re {(?<=85:2F:E7:02:25:74).*(0\/..)}
set output \$expect_out(buffer)
puts \"Result : \$output\"
"
```

and this is the output I am hoping for:

```
Result : 0/10
```

Sadly whenever I try this expect errors our with:

```
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
    while executing
"expect -re {(?<=85:2F:E7:02:25:74).*(0\/..)}"
```

I should also add that trying to escape ? doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tcl` (and so `Expect`) does not support the `(?<=re)` syntax (from `Perl`?). You can try like this:

```
expect -re {85:2F:E7:02:25:74.*(0/..)}
set output $expect_out(1,string)
```

This is from `expect`'s manual:

> Upon matching a pattern (or eof or full_buffer), any matching and
>   previously   unmatched   output   is   saved   in   the  variable
>   `expect_out(buffer)`.  Up to 9 regexp substring matches  are  saved
>   in      the      variables      `expect_out(1,string)`     through
>   `expect_out(9,string)`.